# How can I convert a large PDF to PNG?

Tags: pdf, conversion, jpeg, png

I want to convert a very large PDF file (>2GB) to a PNG (or JPEG) file so that it is easier to open and look at.

I want to do that without opening the PDF file since it is too large to be opened.

Is there any way to do this in either Windows or Linux?

Comment: Check out this other SO: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869908/convert-pdf-to-png-using-imagemagick>. Imagemagick is your friend.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the file contain to be so big? Scanned pages perhaps?

Comment: @DanielB It is an output from a function, it is a large similarity matrix.

Comment: I see. So basically it's just text then. Turning that into an image will probably make things a lot worse.

Comment: @DanielB Oh, it is a figure of similarity matrix, so it is an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick to do that (http://www.imagemagick.org)

If you work under Linux, it is typically installed by default by most distribution, and you call it in the following mannger:

```
convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 85 [SOURCE FILE NAME].pdf [TARGET FILE NAME].png
```

if the PDF file has several pages, the target will be several PNG files, one for each page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm working on company's server, and I couldn't find the covert command.

Comment: `convert` is part of ImageMagick. Your distribution's sure to provide packages for it. It's rather popular, after all.

Comment: What OS are you using? Try to ask the system administrator about it, or getting it installed on the server. It is a very common and pretty standard utility in most Linux distributions (installed by default in many) and can be easily installed also on Windows servers.

Comment: It might still have trouble with larger files. The conversion of a 27MB PDF file errored out after it filled up 1.5GB of available diskspace in '/tmp/'.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this is one of few things to come up on google when searching how to convert PDF to image. I fell into a rabbit hole trying to do the previous answer.

For anyone looking to simply convert PDF pages to PNG, know that you can open it in GIMP, which will extract each page to its own layer. From there you just hit 'Export As' and just type your 'filename.filetype' .